# adding phpdoc to new files

Tags: linux, phpdoc, docblocks

im looking for a way to add some docblocks to a new .php file, so i can have it add the description, package name, author , etc to a new file.

i have been searching for a couple days and I dont see any results on how to add just to 1 .php file, maybe a console command or another utility?

Some sort of generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try PHP_DocBlockGenerator from PEAR -- http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_DocBlockGenerator